# This patent has a legal action that I need explained

Tags: prior-art-request, cn1470762

In the patent application for Chinese patent CN1470762 I found the following note:
Sep 3, 2008 C02 Deemed withdrawal of patent application after publication (patent law 2001)

I need to know what that means and what effect it has on other patents including as prior art.

Comment: Once something is published it stays published and its status as prior art is not changed by subsequent events. Not every application end up resulting in a granted patent.

Answer (score 1):

If the patent have been published it can be used a prior art, regardless of the status of the application.

Filing patents without follow up is sometime done as a defensive measure -- See also the answers [here](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/10216/patent-application-as-defensive-disclosure)

Answer (score 0):

That means that the patent application was abandoned in China.  But as Soren points out, this does not change its value as prior art.